# Gson deserialize LinkedHashmap with nested Objects

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I want to deserialize my Json String with Gson. But deserializing my Json throws me the following error:

> Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface javax.faces.event.BehaviorListener. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.

I created the String already with Gson so there should be all the necessary Data.

I have an LinkedHashmap containing an interface of a few different fields. I already wrote a custom serializer and my json code looks alright. Two of my subclasses use an AjaxBehavior(Listener) and I think this is the problem.

I tried creating an InstanceCreator of my subclasses and of the AjaxBehavior, but both did not change anything.

In the following: FormField is my Interface, formMap is my LinkedHashmap with all data (working). formFields should be a clone of formMap after deserialization works. When everything works formMap will not be there and formFields should be filled from an external Json.

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(FormField.class, new FormFieldDeserializer());
builder.registerTypeAdapter(FormField.class, new FormFieldSerializer());
builder.registerTypeAdapter(AjaxBehavior.class, new BehaviorListenerInstanceCreator());
builder.registerTypeAdapter(FormField.class, new CalendarInstanceCreator());
builder.setPrettyPrinting();
Gson gson = builder.create();

String myJson = gson.toJson(formMap);
System.out.println(myJson);


Type listType = new TypeToken<LinkedHashMap<String, FormField>>(){}.getType();
formFields = gson.fromJson(myJson, listType);
```

Two of my subclasses use the AjaxBehavior:

```
public class CalendarField extends FormField {
    private AjaxBehavior ajax;

    private void setupAjax() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        ajax = (AjaxBehavior) context.getApplication().createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
        ajax.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new InputListener());
        ajax.setTransient(true);
    }
```

And I tried to make an InstanceCreator for it:

```
public class BehaviorListenerInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<AjaxBehavior> {
    @Override
    public AjaxBehavior createInstance(Type type) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        AjaxBehavior ajax;
        ajax = (AjaxBehavior) context.getApplication().createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
        ajax.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new InputListener());
        ajax.setTransient(true);

        return ajax;
    }
}
```

What can I do, to get my objects back in the LinkedHashmap?

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "MyCal": {
    "type": "CalendarField",
    "ajax": {
      "listeners": [
        {}
      ],
      "transientFlag": true,
      "initialState": false
    },
    "id": "MyCal",
    "label": "Mein Datum",
    "FromTo": false
  },
  "MyNumber": {
    "type": "NumberField",
    "IsYear": false,
    "mask": "999?99",
    "ajax": {
      "listeners": [
        {}
      ],
      "transientFlag": true,
      "initialState": false
    },
    "id": "MyNumber",
    "label": "Eine Nummer",
    "FromTo": false
  },
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.

I have to create a TypeAdapter not for AjaxBehavior but for BehaviorListener

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(BehaviorListener.class, new BehaviorListenerInstanceCreator());
```

And inside I return an object of InputListener (subclass of BehaviorListener). The problem was that he wanted to create an object of BehaviorListener, which is an interface, so he crashed.

```
public class BehaviorListenerInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<BehaviorListener> {
    @Override
    public BehaviorListener createInstance(Type type) {
        InputListener ajax = new InputListener();

        return ajax;
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can use this information ;)